# Could not restore packages with MonoDevelop IDE on Linux

Tags: .net-core, monodevelop, aspnetboilerplate, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to open Boilerplate Solution (.NET Core 3.1 ) I've built it using Visual Studio by MonoDevelop IDE on Linux but when opening it and trying restore packages it keeps show me

**could not restore packages** with below details :

```
Detected package downgrade: Abp.ZeroCore from 5.7.0 to 5.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
Detected package downgrade: Abp.ZeroCore from 5.7.0 to 5.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 MySolution.Web.Core -> MySolution.Application -> MySolution.Core -> Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore 5.7.0 -> Abp.ZeroCore (>= 5.7.0) 
 MySolution.Web.Core -> Abp.ZeroCore (>= 5.1.0)
Detected package downgrade: Abp.ZeroCore from 5.7.0 to 5.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 MySolution.Web.Core -> MySolution.EntityFrameworkCore -> MySolution.Core -> Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore 5.7.0 -> Abp.ZeroCore (>= 5.7.0) 
 MySolution.Web.Core -> Abp.ZeroCore (>= 5.1.0)
Detected package downgrade: Abp.ZeroCore from 5.7.0 to 5.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 MySolution.Web.Host -> MySolution.Web.Core -> MySolution.Application -> MySolution.Core -> Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore 5.7.0 -> Abp.ZeroCore (>= 5.7.0) 
 MySolution.Web.Host -> MySolution.Web.Core -> Abp.ZeroCore (>= 5.1.0)
Detected package downgrade: Abp.ZeroCore from 5.7.0 to 5.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 MySolution.Web.Host -> MySolution.Web.Core -> MySolution.EntityFrameworkCore -> MySolution.Core -> Abp.ZeroCore.EntityFrameworkCore 5.7.0 -> Abp.ZeroCore (>= 5.7.0) 
 MySolution.Web.Host -> MySolution.Web.Core -> Abp.ZeroCore (>= 5.1.0)
Restore failed.
Restore failed.
```

So How Could I Open and build .NET Core solution using MonoDevelop IDE on Linux?

Comment: MonoDevelop was not updated to support .NET Core 3.1. Use JetBrains Rider or VSCode please.

Comment: @LexLi Is there community edition for JetBrains Rider(free without a license ) or How could I use VSCode for .NET Core it's for front-end technology ?

Comment: As far as I know, JetBrains only offers free licenses to students/open source projects, no Rider Community edition. VSCode is for everything.